# AEM Apache Felix Console is inactive

Tags: console, apache-felix, aem

Currently I'm working in AEM project (version 6.0)  but when I try to access to the console(author_instance/system/console ) I obtain a 404 error.

Can anyone provide please a way to activate the console?
Is a tool needed to activate the console?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is author_instance your local installation of AEM or is it somewhere behind a dispatcher in a net?

Comment: Sorry for delay, is behind a dispatcher in a net, but I allow all(for now)  in the dispatcher and I can't enter to the console.

Comment: If author_instance is balanced URL, try to enter direct URL (maybe IP address) to the instance. I'm not sure if it even works on balanced URL.